# Efficiently creating new JavaScript object based on an existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best practice to create new JavaScript objects based on an existing object, and extend them with new properties?

The following should work, however, I expect there is a much more efficient solution.

```
<div class="chart" data-type="bar" data-title="My Bar Chart 1" data-foo="Hello"></div>
<div class="chart" data-type="pie" data-title="My Bar Pie" data-foo="Good Morning"></div>
<div class="chart" data-type="bar" data-title="My Bar Chart 2" data-foo="Good Day"></div>
<div class="chart" data-type="bar" data-title="My Bar Chart 3" data-foo="Good Evening"></div>

$('.charts').each(function(){
    $(this).highcharts($.extend( {}, {
        bar: {/* default settings for a bar chart  */ },
        pie: {/* default settings for a pie chart  */ },
        line:{/* default settings for a line chart */ }
      }[$(this).data('type')], {
        title: {text: $(this).data('title')},
        somethingElse: {foo: $(this).data('bar')}
            // ...
      } ));
});
```

Comment: @4castle  Where syntax errors?  I am trying to create different charts based on data contained in the HTML.

Comment: I think I figured it out now. The indentation was throwing me off. The only improvement I see is that the first `{}` is unnecessary.

Comment: @4castle  Yea, using a separate variable would make it more readable.  The part that has we questioning my approach is where I use a certain type often such as the bar chart.  Makes me think I should re-think my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts:

- Only create default settings once
- Only call `$(this)` once per loop
- (Possibly) try calling `$this.data()` to extract all data at once

*Note: this is a classic case of premature optimisation.  Highcharts will be doing far more work than you are creating settings, so it's probably pointless optimising the creation of the settings object!*

With bullet-point suggestions incorporated, your JS would look something like:

```
var defaults = {
    bar: {/* default settings for a bar chart  */ },
    pie: {/* default settings for a pie chart  */ },
    line:{/* default settings for a line chart */ }
};

$('.charts').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data(),
        settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults[data.type], {
            title: { text: data.title },
            somethingElse: { foo: data.bar },
            ...
        });
    $this.highcharts(settings);
});
```

Note: without knowing precisely how complex your default settings are, it's safer to pass the `true` argument to `$.extend` to ensure jQuery does a deep-copy rather than shallow-copy.  (This shallow-vs-deep requirement is also a reason why I'm not echoing @Maxx suggestion to use `Object.assign`, as that doesn't do deep-copies.)

Comment: Thanks searlea,  Yea, I know the performance is negligible compared to highcharts, but want to learn the "right way"  Also, think it is best to use a single object with all the sub-objects like you are doing, and not making a literal object each time via some switch statement?  Thanks!

Comment: The 'right way' depends on context.  You may well find `switch` (or `if-else` style logic) may allow you to structure code better (or just differently), and you could then use ternary operator or idioms like `title: data.title || 'default title'` to construct the object as required.  On the flip-side, using a single defaults object allows you to add additional types (scatter, gauge, spline, ..) in one place, without having to update verbose `switch`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const someObj = {a: 1};
const newObj = Object.assign({}, someObj, {newProp: 2});

console.log(someObj); // {a: 1} same
console.log(newObj); // {a: 1, newProp: 2}
```